# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I'm trying to create a custom view with picture from the drawable folder.
the picture that the program choose from the folder depends on the client so I need to approach the R file with a variable.
after doing a research I found that the way to do it is like that:

```
String uriName = ":drawable/"+thisCard.getKind()+thisCard.getNumber();
int idUri = getResources().getIdentifier(uriName , null , PACKAGE_NAME);
Drawable tmp = getResources().getDrawable(idUri , getContext().getTheme());
cardImage.setImageDrawable(tmp);
```

but I get a RuntimeException of "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0"

when I searched the exception I got answers that told me to do what I did in the paragraph I wrote up.
what am I doing wrong?

also, you can see in the code I added down that I inserted a Log command for debug. when I debugging that line shows twice. Is there a reason why that method called twice when I call it only once?

I added my code and the stacktrace.

This is part of the class (it extends View)

```
public void setCard(Card card){
    thisCard = card;
    isSet = true; 
    //in the Card constructor isSet is false so it does not suppose to go in the method setCardImage() yet.
    invalidate();
}

private void setCardImage(){

    String uriName = ":drawable/"+thisCard.getKind()+thisCard.getNumber();

    try {

        cardImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
        int idUri = getResources().getIdentifier(uriName , null , PACKAGE_NAME);

         Drawable tmp = getResources().getDrawable(idUri , getContext().getTheme());
        cardImage.setImageDrawable(tmp);

        Log.d(TAG , "im here");
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(isSet) {
        setCardImage();
    }
}
```

this is the MainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.testView);
    Card card = new Card("club" , 2);
    testView.setCard(card);

}
```

and this is the StackTrace:

```
08-26 07:54:33.135 2364-2364/com.example.danac.cards E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.danac.cards, PID: 2364
                                                                   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
                                                                       at com.example.danac.cards.CardView.setCardImage(CardView.java:51)
                                                                       at com.example.danac.cards.CardView.onDraw(CardView.java:65)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

thank you

EDIT : 
the xml of that certain view:

```
      <com.example.danac.cards.CardView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/testView"/>
```

Comment: I guess you have, but have you tried to display the idUri to check if the path is the right one?

Comment: are you using .svg drawables??

Comment: @millinet - when I debugged it returned to me with the correct package (PACKAGE_NAME = getContext().getPackageName();

Comment: @Dev - Im using .png if that is what you mean

Answer (score -1):

```
String uriName = ":drawable/"+thisCard.getKind()+thisCard.getNumber();
int idUri = getResources().getIdentifier(uriName , null , PACKAGE_NAME);
```

I guess your uriName is wrong. You can get id of your drawable like:

```
String drawableName = thisCard.getKind() + thisCard.getNumber();
int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", PACKAGE_NAME);
```

You should not add **":drawable"** to your drawable name. You should add **"drawable"** to method `getIdentifier`. Good luck.

Comment: I did what you said and now it throws me a NullPointerException on the imageView although i wrote the line 
    cardImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
In addition, can you tell why is it called twice?

Comment: I did not suggest any imageview code. This is another error i think. Pls post your xml codes.

Comment: Also what is called twice? I dont understand

Comment: Pls edit your question with adding codes, not in comments.

Comment: I edited, added the xml of that view, beside that, thats all the code.
the method setCardImage() called twice somehow. I can tell becouse the exception is thrown twice and the line         Log.d(TAG , "im here"); is printed twice

Comment: So where is ImageView with id cardImage?

Comment: I defined it inside the custom view as a private ImageView cardImage;
is it not the way to do it?

Comment: You call `cardImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cardImage);`, so your **activity_main.xml** should contain an ImageView with id cardImage